# Lightning Component. How to render an EmailTemplate in preview window?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, popup-window

I have a Lightning Component that allows a user to update a custom message before rendering an EmailTemplate and sending it. An Apex controller returns the rendered string and populates an attribute. I would like to preview the template in a popup window when user clicks a preview button. My first guess was something along these lines:

```
openPreview: function(cmp) {
  var newWin = window.open("", "TemplateView", "width=650,height=1000");
  newWin.document.write(cmp.get("v.renderedTemplate"));
}
```

Blank window opens fine but `newWin.document.write` is `undefined` and returns an error. I assume this is due to the [secure-window](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/cli_rules_secure_window.htm?search_text=window.open) patching of the window object. Could someone point to a solution in Lightning to achieve this use case?

Comment: Have you looked into SendEmail quickAction and passing default parameters to it?

Comment: I hadn't no. Though in my instance I had to render a detailed VisualForce template and at first look these apply to lex email templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use SLDS to create a `Modal` (https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/) instead of popup.

This seems useful http://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/04/15/modal-box-lightning-component-salesforce/.

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for the suggestion. My problem with using a Modal was that the returned string is a fully styled HTML document (Email Template) with inline CSS and its own scope etc. The purpose of the preview is to view it 'as is' to show how it will render when sent. I could use an `iframe` inside a modal but I have not found a way to dynamically set the `srcdoc` attribute since Spring18 (worked in Winter18). I think I'm missing something obvious? Could you just insert HTML doc string inside a modal with say `<aura:unescapedHtml>` and expect it to render correctly? Be safe? I'll try, thanks

Comment: I already experienced preview of email via `<aura:unescapedHtml>` and it works BUT you will not have the same rendering as real email (not the same HTML/CSS rendering on browser and Mail engine). But yes, you can put `<aura:unescapedHtml>` in a modal.

Comment: Gave this a shot finally. It works well enough. Thanks.